# Environment deploy with manual input

Tags: github-actions

I need to create a GitHub Actions deploy using environments. I have two environments (dev, test).
I want to kick off the deploy on merge to the develop branch, but the thing is, the deployment needs to take a credential (JWT) as input, and it is a different for each environment.

What is the best way to do this?

I have thought about putting the credentials into a GitHub secret but it would mean updating it periodically throughout the day and not everyone would have access to update secrets. The other option I am swaying towards is to kick off the job but wait for the input, but I'm a novice at GitHub Actions, so not sure if this works, sounds very like a manual kick off with input.

Comment: Depending on where the secret comes from, you could set environment secrets via API directly from where the secret is generated.

Comment: I didn't think about using the gh API to update the secret, good idea.  Not sure I can use it though as the credential is revealed after a log in to a website with 2fa